# selection second row to current row excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, range, rows

I am trying to find, how I can make the selection of rows.

I need make selection from second row to active cell row. Can you help me? Thx

```
Rows("2:ActiveCell.Row").Select
```

I try something like this one, but it´s not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the Active cell. Try,

```
Rows("2:" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
```